# Mapping and transforming CSV with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataset

I've been trying to solve a simple mapping and transforming with Python and Pandas but it seems that I'm not moving in the right direction.

I have a simple CSV file that I need to delete some columns, insert new ones and inject some data into these new columns.

I'm able to add that to a dictionary but I don't know to iterate the data to get each element of the array into a row and not the whole list associated with a key inside of the dictionary.

I was able to find tutorials with pandas but none of them talk about removing/adding columns/new data.

I believe it's simpler to understand reading the code than trying to describe it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# open file
data = pd.read_csv("sample_data.csv")

# delete columns
data = data.drop(['Current Status',
                  'Acquisition Channel',
                  'Attribution',
                  'Contact Record ID'],
                  axis='columns')

# rename Unit Price column to Total
data = data.rename(columns={'Unit Price': 'Total'})

# resort

data_blend = {'CODE': ['1'],
              'Company': data['Company ID'],
              'DEPARTMENT': np.nan,
              'CLASS': np.nan,
              'SALES': data['Total']>0,
              'RETURNS': data['Total']<0,
              'UNITS': data['Quantity'],
              'DATE-TRAN': data['Transaction ID'],
              'TRDATE-CCCCMMDD': data['Date'],
              'SKU-NEW': data['Product ID'],
              'TRX-SOURCE': ['8'],
              'ASSISTED-SALE': ['A'],
              'RET-ORIG-DATE': data['Transaction ID'],
              'RET-ORIG-TERM': data['Date'],
              'TIME-HHMM00': ['AAAAAA'],
              }

modified_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_blend)
```

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: What would your expected output be?

Comment: Code,Company ID,Department,Class,Sales,Returns,Units,Date-Tran ...
1,123,456,Class1,120,0,1,20190926 ...

Comment: @CeliusStingher I take the csv, delete some columns, rename unit price to total and add new columns with fixed information like '1' or 'A' or 'AAAAAA' depending on the column name. My data_blend dictionary is assigning the whole column information (let's say for the key 'Company'). I would need to iterate through the data and append each row accordingly.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand why you use a dictionary here. Can you give an example of output? If you want to iterate over 'company' why don't you iterate and append what you want?

Comment: @DavidE the dictionary was an attempt to use pandas. Here's my input and my output:

input:

User,User ID,Current Status,Email,Retailer ID,User Login,Permission,Type,Store ID,Retailer Store ID,Location,Transaction ID,Date,Product ID,Product Name,Quantity,Unit Price,
Barbara,192,Active,barba@barbara.com,132238,barbara,1,store,123,7777,New York,111122333,2019-01-31 5:00,500088000000,,1,-51,

output:
CODE,COMPANY,DEPARTMENT,CLASS,SALES,UNITS,DATE-TRAN,SKU-NEW,TRX-SOURCE,ASSISTED-SALE,RET-ORIG-DATE,TIME-HHMM00
1,132238,””,””,-51,1,2019-01-31,111122333,8,A,111122333,2019-01-31,AAAAAA

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your need but I will try to do my best.

```
#you can loop over your companies like so:
for company in data['Company ID']:
   # Do whatever, for example test if Total > 0 
   if data["Total"][data['Company ID'] == company] > 0:
      # do something
```

if you want to add columns you can

```
# create a list like so 
my_list = []
# after appending what you want you build a new column like so
data["somename"] = my_list
```

I can't help you more without knowing exactly your problem.